# Replace slash with a single backslash in R

Tags: r, character-replacement

This is probably trivial, but I have failed to find any question referring to this exact issue.
My issue does not have to do with coming up with a suitable regex, it has to do with accurately specifying the replacement part.

```
x = "file_path/file_name.txt" - this is what I have
# "file_path\file_name.txt" - this is what I want
```

Here is what I tried:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(string = x, pattern = "/") # returns TRUE, as expected
#str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "/", replacement = "\") # fails, R believes I'm escaping the quote in the replacement
str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "/", replacement = "\\") # this results to "file_pathfile_name.txt", missing the backslash altogether
str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\") # this results to "file_path\\file_name.txt", which is not what I want
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to escape the escape character which means 4 '\' in the end.

```
cat(gsub('/', '\\\\', "file_path/file_name.txt"))
```

Look at the difference between your standard output with like 'print()' which escapes the escape character, or get the plain string by using 'cat()'.

```
str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\")
cat(str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\"))
```

Comment: This is the last line of my code. It only looks correct because you used `cat()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just added this point to my answer. Cat is not escaping the special characters... Your last line was correct, it just doesn't look correct. You need to get used to this behaviour in R :-)

Comment: I understand: "\\" is what I'm actually looking for. Many thanks for helping me realize it.